# Javascript Field Validation

Tags: javascript, forms

I have three fields ForteID, disposition and Cancel_Disposition.  Right now I have this code in my javascript and it works:

```
function validateForteID(){
  if(document.csform.ForteID.selectedIndex==0)
  {
    alert("Please select your Forte ID.");
    document.csform.ForteID.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if(document.csform.disposition.selectedIndex==0)
  {
    alert("Please select a disposition.");
    document.csform.disposition.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if(document.csform.Cancel_Disposition.selectedIndex==0)
  {
    alert("Please select a disposition.");
    document.csform.Cancel_Disposition.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

What I am looking to do and not exactly sure how to do it, but if the field Disposition is either LOC or Backout, I then want it to do this part of the code:

```
if(document.csform.Cancel_Disposition.selectedIndex==0)
{
  alert("Please select a disposition.");
  document.csform.Cancel_Disposition.focus();
  return false;
}
```

But only if the disposition is LOC or Backout.  Let me know if there I need more explanation, thank in advance!

Comment: It seems like you already know how to use conditionals in javascript, so perhaps you should apply that knowledge to find your solution.

Comment: Your question title reads "PHP Field Validation" but the question is tagged and about JavaScript. Has this anything to do with PHP?

Comment: I am sorry about the title, I ended up striping down the code I entered after I titled it and wrote out the post and didnt realize it.  @MikeBrant well I know how to use an if then statement, but I got this code from a website, and not sure how to do and or statement within it.  I searched for it and I found and statements but not or.

Comment: What other programming languages do you know? Javascript's and/or are just like C, PHP, and many other languages. If you don't know basic programming, you're going to find yourself way over your head -- you can't just cut and paste and expect to be able to get by.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cancel_disposition_value = document.csform.Cancel_Disposition[document.csform.Cancel_Disposition.selectedIndex].value;
if(cancel_disposition_value=='LOC' || cancel_disposition_value=='Backout')
{
    alert("Please select a disposition.");
    document.csform.Cancel_Disposition.focus();
    return false;
}
```